# Unable to import "of" from rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am facing a problem with one angular import statement.

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
```

This is what I am trying. But I am not able to import **of** from rxjs.
When I checked the [official page](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) for rxjs, **of** is available.

Why I am facing this? Can somebody help me in solving this?

Comment: What's the problem?  What version do you have installed?

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`

Comment: In RxJS 6 use `import { of } from 'rxjs';`. For RxJS 5 use `import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';`

Comment: can u try import "rxjs/add/observable/of";?

Comment: @martin thanks. This worked. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use RxJS 5 when you've actually got RxJS 6. You can remove "of" from your import statement and then update your usage for RxJS 6.

This is how I'd return an observable with a value immediately in RxJS 5:

```
return Observable.of("MyString")
```

This is how I've been returning an observable with a value immediately in RxJS 6:

```
return Observable.create( observer => observer.next("MyString"));
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:
**import { Observable, of} from 'rxjs';**

use this line of code to import Observable & of at same time.

***My error:*** error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/observable/of' or its corresponding type declarations.

I spent hours and find this at https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 after looking the imports of this project.

**[SOLVED](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)** at least for me